# Linking sidebarPanels in shiny for SelectizeInput function

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Assume I have a drop down in `sidebarPanel - location` from which I can select a maximum of 2 options. I want to create an if loop where in - chosing 'Saddle Joint' and 'Gliding Joint' from the drop down leads to selection of objects 'x' and 'y' in another `sidebarPanel - datasets` - basically creating a linkage.

I tried this piece of code, but it doesn't work:

```
if (input$location== "Saddle Joint" & input$location== "Gliding Joint") {

  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                           "datasets", "Datasets:", choices = c("x","y"),
                           selected= c("x","y"))
}
```

Do take a look at the screenshot for better picture!

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Su1.png)

Comment: Well your if statement will never be true since `input$location` can't equal Saddle Joint and Gliding Joint at the same time. If `input$location` is a vector with multiple values then you want `"Saddle Joint" %in% input$location & "Glding Joint" %in% input$location`

Comment: @Carl that works! thank you!

Comment: Ok, will submit an answer then.

Comment: @Carl if I have a vector of names, assume for example: as,ad,af.. and so on. How could I determine combinations of two (as,ad; as,af, ad,af) so that I could insert that in if loop something like, if(input$location==all combinations of the vector).. then do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the boolean in your `if` statement. Use this:

```
"Saddle Joint" %in% input$location & "Gliding Joint" %in% input$location
```

Also could use:

```
all(c("Saddle Joint","Gliding Joint") %in% input$location)
```